# Using GraphQL,Springboot,MongoDB.The json is 1000+ lines deeply nested.Instead of updating whole doc,need to update specific key-value at any position

Tags: mongodb, graphql, upsert, graphql-spqr

Requirement for mutation is to behave like upsert. For example in below json mutation is required to change "status" under Rooms->Availability section. Which I do not want to hard code like

```
db.collection.update({
    'Rooms.Availability.status':true
},{
    $set : {
        'Rooms.Availability.status':False
    }
})
```

for specific Array Index because there are possibilities of not having "status" or "Availability" key in some other document.

Below is similar JSON structure. Keys can be different in other JSON documents within same collection.

```
@GraphQLMutation(name = "updateHotelDetails")
public Hotel updateHotelDetails(Hotel h){ // Do I need to pass whole object as argument or only specific key-value?
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(....); // How can I write update code without hard coding?

}
```

Document 1:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("71testsrtdtsea6995432"),
  "HotelName": "Test71testsrtdtsea699fff",
  "Description": ".....",
  "Address": {
    "Street": "....",
    "City": "....",
    "State": "...."
  },
  "Rooms": [
    {
      "Description": "......",
      "Type": ".....",
      "Price": "....."
      "Availability": [
             "status": false,
            "readOnly": false
          ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "......",
      "Type": "....",
      "Price": "..."
      "Availability": [
            "status": true,
            "readOnly": false
          ]
      "newDynamickey": [
            {}
          ]
    },
  ]
  "AdditionalData": [
    {
        "key1": "Vlaue1",
        "key2":"Value2"
    },
    {...}
  ]
}
```